# ZRANGEBYLEX query returns different result for same amount char count

Tags: redis, lexical

I created set like this
`ZADD myzset 0 baba 0 abab 0 aabb 0 bbaa 0 baab 0 abba`

when I query using "aa" and "bb" keyword results like this

**for "aa"**

`ZRANGEBYLEX myzset "[aa" +
1) "aabb"
2) "abab"
3) "abba"
4) "baab"
5) "baba"
6) "bbaa"`

**for "bb"**

`ZRANGEBYLEX myzset "[bb" +
1) "bbaa"`

why "bb" returns only 1 but "aa" returns 6

`ZRANGEBYLEX myindex "[banana:" + LIMIT 1 10
1) "banana:123"
2) "banahhh:1"
3) "banned user:49"
4) "banning:89"`

**Another** from redis site (https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex)

How can `2) "banahhh:1"` this listed as second. it must not be shown in result or am I missing something

`ZRANGEBYLEX myindex "[banana:" + LIMIT 1 10
1) "banana:123"
2) "banahhh:1"
3) "banned user:49"
4) "banning:89"`

Note: I noticed that it sorts added items and return based on sorted index. I wasnt know that

Answer (score 0):

This is because your elements in sorted set has same score and you use the ZRANGEBYLEX command. As the redis documents said :

> While the same element can't be repeated in a sorted set since every element is unique, it is possible to add multiple different elements having the same score. **When multiple elements have the same score, they are ordered lexicographically** (they are still ordered by score as a first key, however, locally, all the elements with the same score are relatively ordered lexicographically).

And you use ZRANGEBYLEX command, it just compare the string with the restriction of same scores.

> If the elements in the sorted set have different scores, the returned elements are unspecified.

So if your sorted-set has different scores, the action is unspecified.

And if you use the ZRANGE command, it will first compare the score, and then compare the string with same score.

please refer the api document for more information  https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex && https://redis.io/commands/zrange

Comment: from redis site (https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) `ZRANGEBYLEX myindex "[banana:" + LIMIT 1 10
1) "banana:123"
2) "banahhh:1"
3) "banned user:49"
4) "banning:89"`

How can this is second  `2) "banahhh:1"` it must not be shown in result or am I missing something

Comment: I didn't see it from this site, and does they have same scores?

Comment: It is just listed by the lex order : banana < banahh < banned < banning

Comment: but `h < n` as lexical order, when I try here (https://try.redis.io/), `banahh` not listed

Comment: ehh, then maybe this is a mistake, you should believe your try